# Cleanest way to convert non null terminating c string to terminating c string

Tags: c++, templates, c-strings, c++03, null-terminated

I have some legacy functions that return non null terminating strings.

```
struct legacy {
    char a[4];  //not null terminated
    char b[20]; //not null terminated 
};
```

I pass a lot these char arrays  around and I need a clean way to convert them to null terminated.

As of right now this is what I was doing:

```
legacy foo;
std::string a(foo.a, sizeof(foo.a));
std::string b(foo.b, sizeof(foo.b));
bar(foo.a.c_str(), foo.b.c_str());
```

Is there a cleaner way I can use classes and templates to reduce this code to something like...

```
legacy foo;
bar(make_null_terminated(foo.a), make_null_terminated(foo.b));
```

Comment: Does `bar()` just take `const char*`? Does it hold onto them or does the lifetime of the ntbs not have to last past the call to `bar()`?

Comment: @Barry bar just takes a `const char*`

Comment: Can you change it to take something else or is that out of your control?

Comment: @Barry, sadly that out of my control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
struct make_null_terminated {
    template <size_t sz>
    make_null_terminated(char (&lit)[sz]) : str(lit, sz) {}
    operator const char* () const { return str.c_str(); }
private:
    std::string str;
}
```

This will allow you to use it the way you want to.

**EDIT** After the tags edit, I got rid of `std::begin` and `std::endl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply:

```
std::string a(std::begin(foo.a), std::end(foo.a));
```

Comment: does std::end assume we already have a null terminating character?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question - can this be encapsulated into a function (template)?

Comment: @andre: It does not.

Comment: @andre, they are also not available in C++03

Comment: c++03 tag just added. Sorry I didnt know

Comment: @DimChtz I just added that myself. I spaced out on a major part. leave the answer for anyone looking for a C++11 solution to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

the cleanest way I can think of is to use the iterator constructor of std::string, a pointer being a kind of iterator.

```
bar(std::string(std::begin(foo.a), std::end(foo.a)).c_str(),
    std::string(std::begin(foo.b), std::end(foo.b)).c_str());
```

what's happening here?

1. construct a string by copying the bytes in foo.a and adding a trailing zero (this is encapsulated in the std::string)
2. ditto for foo.b
3. call the method c_str() on the temporary strings to get a pointer to the null-terminated c-string inside.
4. call bar
5. destroy the temporary strings

Comment: Tooooo much typing :)

Comment: @SergeyA measure twice, cut once. Then it doesn't matter how much typing - you'll never need to touch it again.

Comment: For every invocation of a function which needs data from `legacy`. I believe, OP has much more than one.

Comment: @SergeyA you're probably right. Anyway your second +1 was from me. Good answer.

Comment: Appreciate the nice words. )